# Running an executable in build events. works in TargetDirectory, not ProjectDirectory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post-build-event, build-events

I need to run an executable as a pre or post build event.

I tried calling the executable from my project directory and the program could not find a certain .dll that I am using, even though both projects have a reference to the same .dll.

```
 call "$(ProjectDir)SearchIndexBuilder.exe"
```

I just tried to call the same executable from the bin (target directory) and it ran without the dll error.  Does anyone know why?  I don't want to keep the executable there though, since I believe it would be bad practice.

```
 call "$(TargetDir)SearchIndexBuilder.exe"
```

Also, can I traverse up/down directories in the build events?  Can I concatenate '..\' or something similar to do so?

Comment: Why don't you use a batch file with all the commands available there?

Comment: Okay ill try that I guess

Comment: I don't see how that will help me though